# how to get Itemname and cost on each item button click in android

Tags: android

PrimaryFragment :

```
 public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment {
        ListView list;
        String[] itemname = {
                "Rice",
                "Dal",
                "Juice  Item",
                "IceCream",
                "Pack1",

        };


        String[] Cost = {
                "20$",
                "50$",
                "5$",
                "3$",
                "200$",

        };

        int[] imgid = {
                R.drawable.one,
                R.drawable.two,
                R.drawable.three,
                R.drawable.four,
                R.drawable.five

        };


        int windowwidth;
        int screenCenter;
        int x_cord, y_cord, x, y;
        int Likes = 0;
        RelativeLayout parentView;
        float alphaValue = 0;
        private Context m_context;


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout, container, false);
            MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(),itemname,imgid,Cost);
            list=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
           return rootView;
        }
    }
```

MyCustomAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] result;
    int[] imageId;
    String[] Cost;
    static int counter = 0;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context mainActivity, String[] result, int[] imageId, String[] Cost
    ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.result = result;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.Cost = Cost;
        this.context = mainActivity;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView tv;
        TextView cost;
        ImageView img;
        ImageView plusitem;
        ImageView minusitem;
        TextView itemnumber;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.cost = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.plusitem = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        holder.minusitem = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        holder.itemnumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        holder.plusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });

        holder.minusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });

        return rowView;

    }


}
```

i have get itemname ,cost and imig on each item Button Click of  holder.minusitem and holder.minusitem mean  in Customadpter class please help me how to get that value in  on item button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OnClickListener` you still have access to all of the variables in the preceding code so just reference `result[position]` and `imageId[position]` within the `onClick` method